# How to loop through a ZipEntry recursively

Tags: java, zip

I have a zip file inside a zip file. So i will need to recursively unzip.The input is coming in as a byte array

```
zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[])byteArray));
while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
{
processZip(entry, byteArray);
}
```

Inside the processZip(entry, byteArray) i am reading individual entry. How do i handle it when the entry value is a zip file. How can i convert the zipentry object into a Zipfile or enumerate through it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust `processZip()` to take the `ZipInputStream` as an `InputStream` parameter, instead of the byte array. Internally it should construct another `ZipInputStream` around that `InputStream` and do what you're doing here.

NB Why do you *have* a byte array? You should be reading the `ZipInputStream` directly from the source: a socket, a file, whatever. Don't load files into memory.